# How to filter/compare 2 arrays of objects by single property with lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have the following arrays of objects?

```js
let arr1 = [{
  id: 1,
  props: []
}, {
  id: 2,
  props: []
}, {
  id: 3,
  props: []
}]

let arr2 = [{
  id: 1,
  props: ['a', 'b']
}, {
  id: 3,
  props: []
}]
```

I need to somehow compare these 2 arrays and return a new array that contains only objects which IDs are not in both of the original arrays. So in the case above it should contain only the object with ID 2, since it's only in arr1.

I tried to use

```
let arr3 = _.differenceWith(arr1, arr2, _.isEqual)
```

And it works as long as props array in objects are similar and I don't change it (I'm changing it only in the second array).

I also tried this:

```
let arr3 = _.filter(arr1, o => o.id === _.find(arr2, obj2 => o.id === obj2.id))
```

But that didn't work at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`_.differenceBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#differenceBy) with the wanted key `id` to compare.

```js
let array1 = [{ id: 1, props: [] }, { id: 2, props: [] }, { id: 3, props: [] }],
    array2 = [{ id: 1, props: ['a', 'b'] }, { id: 3, props: [] }],
    difference = _.differenceBy(array1, array2, 'id');

console.log(difference);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Was just about to post a similar answer! :)

Comment: 1 for the golden :)

Comment: @OriDrori, you really have looked this up?

Comment: Nope. Just looked at the [top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/lodash/topusers) recently.

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` and `Object.values` will simplify.

```js
let arr1 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    props: []
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    props: []
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    props: []
  }
];

let arr2 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    props: ["a", "b"]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    props: []
  }
];

const updated = Object.values(
  [...arr1, ...arr2].reduce(
    (acc, curr) =>
      Object.assign(acc, { [curr.id]: curr.id in acc ? "" : { ...curr } }),
    {}
  )
).filter(x => x);

console.log(updated);
```